# Return last call and exit node in 5 seconds

Tags: node.js, process, polling

I am trying to see how many requests can node make in 5 seconds. I want that all the calls should be returned within a period of 5 seconds. "opt" is the links array.

```
    function poll()
{
     async.each(opt, function(entry, callback) {
                count1++;
                request({uri:entry, method: "GET",pool:pool}, function(error, response, body) {
                     count++;
                if(Math.abs(new Date()-d)==5000)
                {

                    process.exit(1);
                }
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                    console.log('Yes '+entry);
                    countYes++;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('No '+entry);
                    countNo++;
                }
               callback();
            });
        }, function(err) {
                            count1--;
                            if(count1==0)  
                                console.log(d+" "+new Date()+"\nTotal "+count+" \nNo"+countNo+" \nYes"+countYes+"/n Duration="+Math.abs(new Date()-d));
        }); 
}

function req() {
    var myDate2=new Date();
    myDate2.setSeconds(myDate2.getSeconds()+5);
    //  console.log(d);
    while(true)
    {
        var d=new Date();
        poll();
        if(d>myDate2)
        {
            break;
        } 



       }

}
req();
```

The last call should be returned in 5 seconds and node should exit.

Comment: setTimeout should probably be your friend here...

Comment: concurrent connections, in series? please specify... You can use `ab` por this purpose.

Comment: @hereandnow78- I tried doing that but the asynchronous calls return much after 5 seconds (node doesn't exit).